# Como incluir colunas em um DataFrame em Julia?

Tags: julia

Tenho o seguinte `DataFrame` genérico com 100 linhas:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(X=LinRange(0.0,2π,100));

first(df, 6)
6×1 DataFrame
 Row │ X
     │ Float64
─────┼───────────
   1 │ 0.0
   2 │ 0.0634665
   3 │ 0.126933
   4 │ 0.1904
   5 │ 0.253866
   6 │ 0.317333
```

Como, por exemplo, calcular o seno dos valores da coluna `X` e inserir
em uma nova coluna `SinX`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Update 2

Além da forma indicada na resposta do [@Romerito morais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/434487/38822) (que está correta), também é possível inserir a coluna utilizando o comando:

```
insertcols!(df, (:SinX => sin.(df[!, :X])))
```

ou através de uma referência direta ao nome (símbolo) da nova coluna:

```
df.SinX = sin.(df.X)
```

Além do acesso direto: `df.X`, o vetor com os dados da coluna X podem ser obtidos utilizando `df[!, :X]` ou `df[:, :X]`.

A diferença é que o símbolo `!`, **quando utilizado na primeira
posição de indexação**, retorna uma visão, e o símbolo `:` retorna uma
cópia dos dados.

Como não há necessidade de cópia (para o exemplo desta resposta), o `!` tem um
desempenho melhor.

Maiores detalhes sobre indexação e visão (*view*) podem ser consultados
na [documentação](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/indexing/#getindex-and-view).

Referência: [insertcols!](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataFrames.insertcols!)

<sub>Julia versão 1.7.1 (2021-12-22)</sub>

---

##### Update 1 (obsoleto)

A forma utilizada para indexar o DataFrame e calcular o seno na resposta, estão obsoletos a partir da versão >= 1.0.

A forma correta do comando para inserir a nova coluna é:

```
df[:SinX] = sin.(df[:, :X])
```

O [ponto](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators) entre a função `sin` e o parenteses indica que é uma operação vetorial, e o índice `[:X]`  indica uma busca por todos os elementos (`:`) da coluna `X`.

Resultado:

```
first(df, 6)
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ X          SinX
     │ Float64    Float64
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ 0.0        0.0
   2 │ 0.0634665  0.0634239
   3 │ 0.126933   0.126592
   4 │ 0.1904     0.189251
   5 │ 0.253866   0.251148
   6 │ 0.317333   0.312033
```

Para mais detalhes, consulte o manual (em inglês): [`DataFrames.jl`](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/)

---

##### Original (obsoleto)

Para incluir a nova coluna, basta atribuir o(s) valor(es) a essa nova coluna.

Exemplo:

```
df[:SinX] = sin(df[:X])
head(df)

    X                   SinX
1   0.0                 0.0
2   0.06346651825433926 0.0634239196565645
3   0.12693303650867852 0.12659245357374926
4   0.19039955476301776 0.1892512443604102
5   0.25386607301735703 0.2511479871810792
6   0.3173325912716963  0.31203344569848707
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Acho que usar a função `map` é mais eficiente pela questão da composição, assim você não precisa percorrer o `DataFrame` duas vezes, uma inicilizando e a outra atribuindo um valor funcional.

```
df[:error] = map((x,y) -> x-y , df[:A], df[:B])
```

apesar de especificamente no seu caso ela levar apenas a mais código, creio que leva ao um entendimento melhor.

```
df[:SinX] = map((x) -> sin(x), df[:X])
```

Isso quer dizer que, para cada entrada de `df[:X]` mapeie para uma nova entrada aplicando a função `sin(x)`

Comment: A atribuição direta percorre o DataArray `df[:X]` apenas uma vez, da mesma forma que o `map`. Apesar de o código gerado pelas duas formas ser bem parecido ([`@code_lowered()`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/base/#Base.code_lowered)), a atribuição direta é mais eficiente que o `map` (para o exemplo da pergunta, cerca de 790 vezes mais rápida e consumo de memória 450 vezes menor), pois evita verificações e conversões de tipos (para visualizar esses problemas: `@code_warntype(map((x) -> sin(x), df[:X]))`)

Comment: nesse caso em expecífico sim, por que você está usando só uma variável, minha ideia foi dar uma opção pra quem tiver que mapear algo derivado de dois campos.

Answer (score 1):

Versao **1.3.1**

Exemplo:

```
df[!, :SinX]  = sin.(df[:, :x])
```